# Обновление игровых файлов

Tags: c++, c, разработка-игр

Я разрабатываю игру на C++ с использованием DirectX 9. Это 3D шутер от первого лица (так планируется). В корневой папке с проектом есть ресурсы игры, такие как: **configs**, **models**, **sounds** и **locations**. К этим файлам очень легко получить доступ. Любой пользователь может заменить модели, звуки или вообще украсть их... Я разработал контейнер, где я упаковываю игровые ресурсы в архив, типа: **configs.pck**, **models.pck** и т.д. Игра работает через лаунчер, где этот инструмент проверяет HASH суммы файлов. Данные он берет с сервера. И тут я встретил проблему, которую я не как не могу решить. Как-то эти все файлы нужно обновлять!

Я написал совершенно другую программу, где в корневых файлах ищет версии всех клиентов игры. И создает их патчи. То есть ищет один файл в старой сборке и в новой. Через бинарный анализ ищет байты, которые не хватает в старой сборке или тех, которых воообще нет. Честно? Анализатор вышел очень плохой. Патчи были размером больше, чем оригинал файла. Так как сохранялось и стартовая позиция offset байта и длина и сами данные. Учитывались флаги состояния буфера. Или заменить, или удалить и т.д. Следовательно из-за корявого анализатора не получилось и грамотно сделать и патчинг этих самых файлов. Игровой движок вылетал с ошибкой, что файлы были повреждены. А лаунчер бесконечно старается решить проблему с HASH суммами файлов. Так как после патчинга они всегда разные.

В анализаторе нужно учитывать не просто замена байтов. Эта замена может быть не просто с 3 байтами 0x1, 0x2, 0x3 на 0x15, 0x2, 0x1. А в оригинале может быть и больше байтов, чем в старом блоке. Нужно учитывать множество факторов, чтобы анализатор понял, что с этим куском данных делать.

***Небольшая дополнительная информация о этапах загрузки***
При парсинге карты и ее сборки, в ней же лежат ссылки на long offsets блоках данных. Эти блоки нужны для того, чтобы как бы вытягивать модели из контейнера. Я ставлю нужный offset из карты в поток чтения models.pck и начинаю читать первые 4 байта - это длина одной модели. Как только данные считались, идет расшифровка простым XOR с ключем (Который загружается с сервера).

Подскажите куда мне копать? Где посмотреть формулы? Есть может у кого готовое решение?

Comment: @user7860670 в правилах сайта нет ограничений по банальности, простоте, глупости или другим подобным странным критериям

Comment: А какой движок вы используете? И какие байты проверяет ваш патчер? *(вы уверены, что там либо нет проверок по хэш-сумме, либо вы их правильно патчите?)*. С таким маленьким количеством деталей о вашем коде это может быть какая угодно проблема.

Comment: Что реально у нас спрашивают: Как написать алгоритм обновления  файлф, с условием, что редакторское предписанние должно быть как можно коротким.

Ответ - почитайте про алгоритм в Rsync.

Эта задача не имееет отношения к контролю целостности игровых файлов.

Comment: @mazik7512 я свой игровой движок написал с использованием DirectX9. Проверяю самые обычные байты файлов. Я их считываю как бинарные данные. К сожалению, все что я писал про патч удалил из-за того, что слишком плохо работало. Поэтому без кода

Comment: Постарайтесь конкретизировать вопрос, а то тут вперемешку и ошибки хешей, и алгоритма, и поведения лаунчера, и куски данных и отсылки на неприведенный код ..

Comment: @Kromster я дополнил вопрос деталями. Ошибка только в алгоритме. Хеши и все прочее дал для деталей происходящего

Comment: Стало еще запутаннее. На кой ляд в карте смещения блоков данных, а не обычные идентификаторы по именам?

Comment: Я вам указал в краце на проблему - это только в алгоритме анализа и парсинга, все.

Comment: Если проблема только в алгоритме сравнения двух комплектов зашифрованных файлов, то ответ я уже дал - сравнивайте и стройте дифф _ДО_ шифрования, а локатор ресурсов дополните работой с патчами, и будет все хорошо )

Comment: При обновлении файлов: файлы скачивать с сервера пофайлово. (Не sounds.pck, а sounds/sound123.mp3.pck, если файлы часто обновляются по одному.)
Не мудрите.

Comment: Вообще-то нет, да и так глупо делать. Скачивается готовый патч! Вы не мудрите. Для кого я выше писал? И что вы вообще пишете? Какой еще sound123.mp3.pck? Расширение на над расширением?

Comment: Кстати зря негодуете, расширения вполне себе нормально аккумулировать подобным образом.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Нашел на просторах гита вот такое решение: https://github.com/google/diff-match-patch/blob/master/cpp/diff_match_patch.cpp

Полностью решил свои все проблемы, спасибо всем кто пытался помочь.

Comment: "The Diff Match and Patch libraries offer robust algorithms to perform the operations required **for synchronizing plain text**." - стоит учесть, что это декларируется как дифф для текста, а не бинарных данных.

Comment: @Kromster любые бинарные данные можно интерпретировать как текст в кодировке ISO 8859-1 

Comment: @andreymal просто обратил внимание, что работа с текстом может иметь неожиданные подводные камни типа смены CR/LF, добавки BOM, чудной интерпретации #0-#31 и т.п. Поэтому лучше погонять на тестах, убедиться что их там нет ) *Давеча вот мне загрузчик текста как раз сюрприз преподнес тем, что на автомате в конец EOL дописывал, хотя никто его об этом не просил* ))

Comment: @andreymal да, у меня сразу же в первое что в голову пришло это то, что он работает только с простым текстом. Поэтому я открыл бинарник в простом редакторе, скопировал небольшой кусочек и вставил в тестовый бокс. Все прошло успешно.

Comment: Ну, я скажу одно, как то давно, года 2 назад вышла игра,  NieR Replicant, так мы ее за 4 дня вскрыли, так что ничего такого не поможет как минимум от распаковки ресурсов, однако замедлит это действие, а по поводу упаковки и патчей, то стоило бы иметь несколько файлов, один как маппинг, который ссылается на другие файлы, и там же имеет блоки с шифрованием/сжатием, например тот же zstd, и уже потом в других файлах лежали бы оффсеты, прыжки, блоки данных, и так далее.

Comment: @ori да, знаю. Я и сам одну mmo вскрыл, в которой все файлы были сжаты и зашифрованы. Я не хочу что-то уникальное сделать и тратить на это время. "Защита от дурака" и только)

Answer (score 0):

Предположения и допущения (прошу уточнить в комментариях, верно ли я полагаю):

- вопрос по сути о том, как организовать апдейтер для ресурсов игры.
- упакованные ресурсы зашифрованы (либо шифром, либо архивированием, иначе толку от простой упаковки в вашем сценарии почти ноль).
- в идеальном случае, зашифрованные и/или упакованные данные - это белый шум (а иначе, дешифровка и распаковка нехитрое дело). Разница между двумя "шумами" равна шуму.

Таким образом, построение дифференциальной разницы *ПОСЛЕ* создания упаковок - нецелесообразно. Надо её делать на шаге *ДО* упаковки.

1. Берете, например, корпус ресурсов версии 1.0 и сравниваете его с корпусом 1.1. Для простоты - можно просто по-файлово. Получаете дифф.разницу (уж тут должно быть тривиально, какие файлы добавились, какие удалились, какие заменились).
2. Пакуете и шифруете разницу, называете например `patch1.pck`.
3. Теперь игре надо уметь, при загрузке составить карту ресурсов на текущую версию. Т.е. определить, что будет взято из оригинального `models.pck`, а что из `patch1.pck` (а что из `patch2.pck`, а что более недоступно, т.к. удалено).
4. Играете.

Разумеется, тут возможны дальнейшие оптимизации типа:

- делать дифф не по файлам, а по содержимому с использованием более хитрых алгоритмов (например Венгерского) для минимизации размера диффа (см. комментарии про rsync).
- при апдейте перепаковывать ресурсы, внедряя патч в ресурсы.
- делать кросс-патчи для разных версий
- итп итд

---

P.S. Важно понимать, что от воровства ресурсов 100% защиты нет. Подменная DLL-ка с потрохами выдаст все модели, текстуры и шейдеры. Так что шифровка - это защиты от дурака, не более. Соответственно не тратьте на нее слишком много сил и времени.

Comment: По-моему из текста вопроса никак не следует наличие шифрования

Comment: @andreymal просто я сам в разработке игр и это очевидное положение, что раз идет упаковка ради предотвращения кражи (а не ускорения чтения с HDD например), то эта упаковка делается с паролем или как минимум security through obscurity.

Comment: Для вас очевидное, для автора вопроса скорее всего нет, раз он о шифровании ничего не упоминает

Comment: @andreymal я использую простое XOR шифрование, лишь данных.То есть, структура пакета следующая: первые 4 байта - количество моделей.Структура данных идет по очереди лежащих в контейнере.То есть: 8 байта - это код положения в контейнере.Он генерируется в процессе упаковки.Другие 4 байта - это длина данных модели.А дальше сами данные.Вот меня загружается сцена.Она ссылается на контейнер с кодом положения модели. ifstream я сдвигаю от начала позицию и считываю нужную мне модель. через XOR расшифровываю.Так мне не нужно загружать весь пакет целиком, а лишь те части, которой нужны для сцены.

Comment: @andreymal то, что вы написали и так знал) Да и я писал так. Вот правда проблема с алгоритмом выполнения. С патчингом и особенно анализом.

Comment: @andreymal даже если для ТС шифрование (в т.ч. архивированием) неочевидно, это никак не инвалидирует общий принцип изложенный в ответе - создание инкрементальных патчей. Парируете? )

Comment: @Kromster нет, к сути ответа у меня никаких претензий) Тем более автор наконец упомянул шифрование